# d3 force layout dynamic spring force

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, force-layout

Is there a way in d3 force directed graph layout to attach to each edge (aka link), a **dynamic** spring force? 
 Meaning, a force that acts like Kx where x is the distance between the nodes and at **each iteration** (aka "tick"), this force is being updated according to new distance? 
Of course, I want this force to be calculated as part of the entire forces that exist in the system. 
I **know** the "linkDistance" attribute, but this attribute is evaluated only once, and not after each iteration.

Comment: Actually, "linkDistance" is used at each iteration of the force algorithm. It is *evaluated* only once, and this is to fill a table for quick access within the loop.